# Can "hoffentlich" be used familiarly and between close friends (in writing) or does it show formality?

Tags: word-usage, informal

For example:

> Hoffentlich geht es dir zur Zeit besser ?

Is it typical in such case or is there a better word.

Comment: Neither, it is just polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am german and I'd say, that it's possible to say it like that but would rather go for a more personal

"Ich hoffe es geht dir gerade/aktuell/jetzt besser."

"zur Zeit" is something I wouldn't say but what i also wouldn't consider too formal.